# What is the difference in the user defined in Dockerfile and docker-compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile as below:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:latest

USER root

RUN whoami

USER jenkins

RUN whoami
```

and this docker-compose file

```
version: '2'
services:

  test:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    container_name: test
    hostname: test

    ports:
      - '8080:8080'

    user: root
```

I am wondering

1. What is the difference between the user that is defined in the docker-compose and the user that is defined in the dockerfile
2. How to see the logs of the build stage? When I `RUN whoami`, how and where I can see the result?

What if question is if I change the user in docker-compose to `other`

```
version: '2'
services:

  test:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    container_name: test
    hostname: test

    ports:
      - '8080:8080'

    user: other
```

Why isn't it working

And if I change the dockerfile to

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:latest

USER root

RUN whoami

RUN groupadd -g 999 docker && \
 usermod -aG staff,docker jenkins

USER jenkins

RUN whoami
```

and change the docker-compose to

```
version: '2'
services:

  test:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    container_name: test
    hostname: test

    ports:
      - '8080:8080'

    user: jenkins
```

Still not working.

3. What is the problem
4. Another question is when I do `docker exec -it container_name bash`
   It get access to the container as a root user. How to change that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `user` config in the docker-compose file will overwrite the user used to execute the command in your container. If you omit it, it will use the last `USER` set in your Dockerfile. If you have neither, it should default to root.

Note that your `whoami` commands are run at build-time (not at run-time) so they should not be impacted by what you specified in your docker-compose file which is overriding the user at run-time only.

To see the entire build log, you can use `docker compose build --progress flat`.